# Server returned HTTP response code: 400 facebook

Tags: java, jsp

I'm gettting a problem:

> ERROR : Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL
>
> URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id%2Cname%2Cemail%2Cgender&
>   access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Below is my code :

```
public String getFBGraph() {
    String graph = null;

    try {

        String g ="https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id%2Cname%2Cemail%2Cgender&"+accessToken;


        URL u=new URL(g);
        URLConnection c=u.openConnection();


        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        StringBuffer b=new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine=in.readLine())!=null)
            b.append(inputLine+"\n");
        in.close();
        graph=b.toString();
        //System.out.println(graph);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        throw new RuntimeException("ERROR in getting FB graph data. "+e);
    }
    return graph;

}
```

I'm getting error while I run it from calling method and when I copy paste same url to browser getting output, please help me my accesstocken is perfect, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you just forgot to add `access_token=` parameter name to your URL string:

`String g ="https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id%2Cname%2Cemail%2Cgender&"+accessToken`

Facebook will respond with the HTTP status code 400, in this case:

> 10.4.1 400 Bad Request
>   The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

and will say something along the lines of

> "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

in the response body.

Comment: @HareshPrajapati Have you tried to output the generated URL, with `System.out.println(g)` and open it in the browser ? It also would be nice to take a look at the full response body (for the 400 error), as it will normally provide some details on what is wrong with the request.